# PHP Creating a short array from a list

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to dynamically create a short array with a list of objects. This is for a POST request with the Guzzle client. That's why I need it in a short array.

example of a Guzzle post request:

```
 $res = $this->client->request($methode, $request_url, [
            'form_params' => [
                'param' => 'value'
            ]
         ]);
```

Problem case:

I have got a List: *Params* of Objects: *Param*.
Param has three attributes *id*, *name*, *link_id*.

Let's say the List has three Object.

```
param(1, email, 1)
param(2, username, 1)
param(3, password, 1)
```

I want to dynamically create from the list an array with the [short array syntax](https://coderwall.com/p/uftu7g/php-5-4-shorthand-for-arrays).

Example(Pseudo):

```
for each params as param

 [
   'form_params' => [
     param->name => 'value'
   ]
 ]
```

the result of this code will be like this

```
 [
   'form_params' => [
     'email' => 'value',
     'username' => 'value',
     'password' => 'value'
   ]
 ]
```

Code example:

```
$params = array(
   "param" => array (
      "id" => "1",
      "name" => "username",
      "link_id" => "1",
   )
);

$value = '';
$shortarray = '';
foreach($params as $key => $param){
  $shortarray .= $param->name . '=>' . $value . ',';
}

$postParams = ['form_params' => [ .  $shortarray . ]];
```

I really could use some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share your input clearly?

Comment: Does this make it more clear? Could you give me feedback on the code I have written in the example.

Comment: I am talking about input array which you are getting.

Comment: I have added the array that the foreach uses as input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just show short array syntax than this solution may helps you to resolve you problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207172/4781882

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you require it be a "short array", but here's a solution...

I assume this is a web form, yes?

So let's assume you name your forms in a way that is usable, like:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourform.html">
Line 1 <input name="email1"> | <input name="user1"> | <input name="password1">
<br/>-------<br/>
Line 2 <input name="email2"> | <input name="user2"> | <input name="password2">
<br/>-------<br/>
Line 3 <input name="email3"> | <input name="user3"> | <input name="password3">
</form>
```

Then...

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ {
  $postparms[] = ['email' => $_POST['email'.$i], 'user' => $_POST['user'.$i], 'password' => $_POST['password'.$i] ];
}

print_r($postparms);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm building a short array for a POST request with GuzzleClient. This is not what I'm looking for. Sorry I'll add more context to it. –